# Can I use raster jpg, png images for Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

What I'm trying to achieve is to **map icons, labels, polygons to raster images.
And to have an ability to zoom.**

> I.e. to map furniture to offices / buildings.

Also it's needed to be said that user should work with it through API (through web site interface).

Recently I've spot Mapbox.
While Mapbox is awesome and seems to be a good fit to achieve my goal, I find it hard to find docs for implementing it.

What I've found so far is:

- I can use `mapbox-gl-draw` to draw polygons
- I can upload datasets. Which consist of position, data. With that I can upload icons, labels and probably polygons.

> The missing puzzle is: How I can work with raster images?

and

> Should I position (edit) icons, labels on my own and later save to `dataset`? Or there already exist a functionality drag-drop out-of-box?

One idea is to use Mapbox with transparent background and to zoom raster image separately. Kind of synchronizing it with the map.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I believe this example from the mapboxGL examples shows what you're looking for: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/.

Note that the radar layer, while it looks like a layer constructed in data, is simply a gif added as an image layer, with a bounding box of of four lngLat coordinates. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/radar.gif